# i need to Count through list

Tags: python

I have multiple lists and a big list of lists, I want to check if the big list have some of my small lists and count but I don't want redundancy , example:

```
list1 = [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D"]
List2 = ['K' , "l" , "M"]

main_lists = [["A","C","K","L"] , ["B" , "C" , "M"]]

count1 = 0
count2 = 0
```

what I need is to cont like if I found any item in main list in my two lists I increase a counter
but not redundant so my output of this case should be 
count 1 = 2
count 2 = 2

no important that A and C in the list of my list, just 1 of them will increase the count, what should I do

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your explanation. Can you try to explain more clearly how we are to calculate the count values? Do you have any code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
list2 = ['K', "l", "M"]

main_lists = [["A", "C", "K", "L"], ["B", "C", "M"]]
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

count1 = sum(any(ie in set1 for ie in e) for e in main_lists)
count2 = sum(any(ie in set2 for ie in e) for e in main_lists)

print(count1)
print(count2)
```

Comment: This works, as long as order doesn't matter inside the individual lists, and you don't care which specific lists they are.